# getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: MAC data does not match" while creating a TLS connection

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]
![enter image description here][3]

I am trying to create a secure connection between client and server.
Client is supporting TLSv1.2 and Server is supporting TLSv1.0.
But getting  "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: MAC data does not match" exception.

```
here is the printstacktrace :

    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: MAC data does not match.
            at com.rsa.sslj.x.aJ.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.rsa.sslj.x.aJ.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.rsa.sslj.x.aJ.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.rsa.sslj.x.aU.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.rsa.sslj.x.aU.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.rsa.sslj.x.aU.h(Unknown Source)
            at com.rsa.sslj.x.cI.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.startHandshake(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:361)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:225)
            at com.cisco.ccm.admin.utilities.LdapUtil.validateHost(LdapUtil.java:383)
            at com.cisco.ccm.admin.utilities.LdapUtil.validateHost(LdapUtil.java:289)
```

I checked in my code the enabled protcols are SSLv3, TLSv1 , TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 using getEnabledProtocols() method.
I have read in the TLSv1.2 rfc that if the server is supporting the lower version of TLS then client, client should negotiate with lower version of TLS.

But in my case, i am getting the above exception.(why ??... that shouldnot happen and negotiate with the TLSv1).

NOTE : Also, if i set the enabled protocol as TLSv1 only, then i am able to create a TLS connection.

Please help me out.
Thanks

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC4Ha.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjXjq.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIRvF.jpg
```

Comment: I guess the negotiation ain't working properly. But I can't comment more as will need screenshot of pcap with wireshark and see the ServerHello message being sent by the server.

Comment: There is a big difference in how encryption and decryption work in TLS1.2 as supposed to TLS1.0 so you are getting this error.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of pcap , server hello and client hello. Also i have read that TLS 1.2 is backward compatible, so it should negotiate...right ?

Comment: @Narendra Pathai one more question ..."mac data does not match" and "bad_mac_record" are the same errors or different ?

Comment: Both are same AFAIK. That is possible only when decryption process decrypted some invalid value and found MAC to be invalid.

Comment: I have seen the pcaps and can you also share the detail of Certificate, Client Key exchange by expanding it? I just want to check out the client response to Server Hello.

Comment: What type of service are you using? Do you need the Java Cryptography Extension?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a problem of version incompatible. One thing for sure is that TLS is the new name for SSL. Namely, SSL protocol got to version 3.0; TLS 1.0 is "SSL 3.1". TLS versions currently defined include TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

Also, the following wiki link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) shows that

```
All TLS versions were further refined in RFC 6176 in March 2011 removing their backward compatibility with SSL such that TLS sessions will never negotiate the use of Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) version 2.0.
```

Also between TLS and SSL, the MAC/HMAC differs (TLS uses HMAC whereas SSL uses an earlier version of HMAC). I am suspecting that somehow your code still might be picking us SSL. Could you please disable SSL and try again?

Comment: but i am using tlsv1.2 and tlsv1. PLease find the pcap images.